# Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'WebApp' does not exist in the namespace 'Fax' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, rightfax

I am facing the error, while accessing `RightFax` SDK on IIS through the browser. I need to access Right Fax SDK API through IIS:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'WebApp'
> does not exist in the namespace 'Fax' (are you missing an assembly
> reference?)
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 27:     using System.Web.WebPages; Line 28:     using
> System.Web.WebPages.Html; Line 29:     using Fax.WebApp; Line 30:
> using Fax.WebApp.languages; Line 31:     using System.Web.Mvc;
>
> Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary
> ASP.NET
> Files\rightfaxsdk_api\0e7addb8\6d101f6a\App_Web_index.cshtml.f774d6f8.pdiaoqvl.0.cs
> Line: 29

Comment: please provide some more information

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'WebApp' does not exist in the namespace 'Fax' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Source Error:


Line 27:     using System.Web.WebPages;
Line 28:     using System.Web.WebPages.Html;
Line 29:     using Fax.WebApp;
Line 30:     using Fax.WebApp.languages;
Line 31:     using System.Web.Mvc;

Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\rightfaxsdk_api\0e7addb8\6d101f6a\App_Web_index.cshtml.f774d6f8.pdiaoqvl.0.cs    Line: 29

Answer (score 0):

You can find that dll on the server where you installed the Web SDK in IIS.  Copy the dll to your solution and add it as a reference in your project.  You also need the proper ‘using’ statement too...